# Entity Framework model change error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, datacontext

I am getting the error

> "The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database".

I am using Entity Framework and have changed my model after declaring `DataContext`. How can I fix this error?

Comment: which Entity Framework you are using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If you already deployed your application or you don't want remove data from database you must read about Code First Migrations. Here you have a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh770484(v=vs.103).aspx
2. If you can delete database just do it. EF will create new database that match your model.
3. You can also disable creating/updating database structure by invoking the following code:

   ```
   Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
   ```

Answer (score 11):

If you delete the `__MigrationHistory` table in SQL Server it should fix it.

Comment: Deleting all the rows in that table also seems to have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I used database first to create a project after I had changed my database context 
and solved my problem:

```
Database.SetInitializer<Models.YourDbContext>(null);
```

Don't forget to handle the `DbUpdateException`

Answer (score 0):

**Delete the __MigrationHistory table in SQL Server or just all rows of this table it should fix it**