# The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed since the database was created

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use Code First with Migrations. Even though there are no current changes to my model, I'm getting an exception. When I add a migration, the up and down are empty, but I get a runtime error with the message as follows:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model backing the 'MyDataContext' context
>   has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First
>   Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?

My architecture is as follows:

- DataAccess project that includes the context, fluid configurations and migrations code
- Model project that contains the poco classes
- Web API and MVC projects that each contain the connections string in their respective web.config files.

Additionally I have the following code:

DbInitializer

```
public static MyDataContext Create()
{
   Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDataAccess.MyDataContext, MyDataAccess.Migrations.Configuration>());
   return new MyDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDataContext"].ConnectionString, null);
}
```

I started with AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false; in the migration Configuration constructor, as it was my understanding that this would allow (and require) me to have more control over when migrations were applied.  I have also tried setting this to true but with the same result.

I added a new migration upon receiving this error, and the Up method was empty.  I updated the database to this new migration, and a record was created in the _migrationHistory table, but I still receive the error when I attempt to run the application. Also, the seed data was not added to the database.

```
protected override void Seed(MyDataAccess.MyDataContext context)
{
            IdentityResult ir;

            var appDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(appDbContext));
            ir = roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
            ir = roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Active"));
            ir = roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("InActive"));

            var userNamager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(appDbContext));

            //  assign default admin
            var admin = new User { UserName = "administrator", Email = "myAdmin@gmail.com" };
            ir = userNamager.Create(admin, "myp@55word");

            ir = userNamager.AddToRole(admin.Id, "Admin");
 }
```

where

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyDataContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    ...
```

The question:  If Add-Migration isn't seeing any change in the model, why do I get this error when I run?  Why isn't the seed code being hit? How do I fix this, or if that can't be determined, how do I further determine the root cause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me.

Go to Package Manager Console and Run - Update-Database -force

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks a lot. I was stuck for many days and always ended up cloning entire project again and building. Thank you again!

Comment: so, could you tell me the process...where to find Package Manager Console this ?

Comment: In Visual Studio --> Tools Menu

Answer (score 26):

I am not sure if you found the answer to your problem, but this other answer I found here actually did it for me:
[Entity Framework model change error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010190/entity-framework-model-change-error)

I actually ended up deleting the `__MigrationHistory` table in SQL Server which I didn't know it was being created automatically.

The article also talks about the option to not generate it I think by using this instruction: `Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);` but I have not used it, so I am not sure if it works like that

Comment: Simply deleting all the rows seem to also have the same effect.

Comment: While exporting LocalDB to SQL server, I didn't see the script and _migrationhistory moved along with the script. You saved my day, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I bet your data context is not hooking up the connection string.
Check if it's not initialized with a localdb (something like `(localdb)\v11.0`) and not working with that when you might think it's set to something else.

Comment: +1 I always get this error when i do not check out my local connection string from the source code (Git Cherry-pick Local configs)

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being a conflict between Automatic Migrations being enabled and the initializer MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818489.aspx).